# Call method from a .groovy file in another .groovy file

Tags: groovy, spock

I would like to call a test method from a .groovy file:

```
    void "Test 02"() {
    when: ...
    then: ...
}
```

in another groovy file:

```
package ...
import ...
@Stepwise
@IntegrationTest
@SuppressWarnings(["AbcMetric", "MethodSize"])
@Log4j2
class FullSpec extends GebReportingSpec { ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why would you want to do it with your spock tests?

Comment: This question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). You are explaining **how** you want to do something instead of explaining **what** you actually want to achieve, which limits the scope of answers unnecessarily. My impression is that probably you are doing the wrong thing, but it is impossible to say for sure, because you only present an incoherent set of code snippets instead of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read!) or at least two full test classes. I need those in order to confirm an idea what you might be doing wrong.